# How do I stack Plack authentication handlers?

Tags: perl, session, authentication, plack

I would like to have my Plack app try several different means of authorizing the user.  Specifically, check if the user is already authorized via a session cookie, then check for Digest authentication and then fall back to Basic.

I figured I could just enable a bunch of Auth handlers in the order I wanted them to be checked (Session, Digest, Basic).  Unfortunately, the way that [Plack::Middleware::Auth::Digest](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Plack::Middleware::Auth::Digest) and [Plack::Middleware::Auth::Basic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Plack::Middleware::Auth::Basic) are written they both return 401 if digest or basic auth doesn't exist, respectively.

How is this normally dealt with in Plack?

Comment: Don't have an answer for you, but isn't 404 is completely wrong for that?

Comment: Right, 40one11111 (damn comment limit)

Comment: @ysth Yeah, that's one of the things miyagawa suggested when I asked him.  More importantly, I'm more deeply redesigning this project so it doesn't require effectively writing its own framework in raw Plack to match its historical quirks.  Then I can use Catalyst or Dancer or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have an implementation but I think I have the approach. You can do this "in-line" with [Plack::Middleware::Conditional](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Plack%3a%3aMiddleware%3a%3aConditional). So it would look like this but you'll have to fill in the missing conditions/tests. I didn't see an easy/obvious way but I suspect you might. Since you have the `$env` to pass around you should be able to set/check HTTP_/session stuff in the order you want and keep the state for the next handler to know if it should be enabled or not.

```
use Plack::Builder;

my $app = sub {
    [ 200,
      [ "Content-Type" => "text/plain" ],
      [ "O HAI, PLAK!" ]
    ];
};

builder {
    enable "Session::Cookie";
    enable_if { my $env = shift;
                # I don't know...
            } "Auth::Digest",
                realm => "Secured", secret => "BlahBlah",
                    authenticator => sub { $_[0] eq $_[1] };
    enable_if { my $env = shift;
                # I don't know...
            } "Auth::Basic",
                authenticator => sub { $_[0] eq $_[1] };
    $app;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going to need to write your own middleware, since ideally (based on a very quick read of [RFC 2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt)) when not authenticated you would return a WWW-Authenticate header with both Basic and Digest challenges (with Basic first, for user agents that only understand Basic).